# Deserialize nested array as ArrayList with Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have a piece of JSON, that looks like this:

```
{
  "authors": {
    "author": [
      {
        "given-name": "Adrienne H.",
        "surname": "Kovacs"
      },
      {
        "given-name": "Philip",
        "surname": "Moons"
      }
    ]
   }
 }
```

I have created a class to store Author information:

```
public class Author {
    @JsonProperty("given-name")
    public String givenName;
    public String surname;
}
```

And two wrapper classes:

```
public class Authors {
    public List<Author> author;
}

public class Response {
    public Authors authors;
}
```

This is working, but having two wrapper classes seems to be unnecessary. I want to find a way to remove `Authors` class and have a list as a property of Entry class. Is something like that is possible with Jackson?

## Update

Solved that with custom deserializer:

```
public class AuthorArrayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Author>> {

    private static final String AUTHOR = "author";
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final CollectionType collectionType =
            TypeFactory
            .defaultInstance()
            .constructCollectionType(List.class, Author.class);

    @Override
    public List<Author> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        JsonNode nodeAuthors = objectNode.get(AUTHOR);

        if (null == nodeAuthors                     // if no author node could be found
                || !nodeAuthors.isArray()           // or author node is not an array
                || !nodeAuthors.elements().hasNext())   // or author node doesn't contain any authors
            return null;

        return mapper.reader(collectionType).readValue(nodeAuthors);
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = AuthorArrayDeserializer.class)
public void setAuthors(List<Author> authors) {
    this.authors = authors;
}
```

Thanks @wassgren for the idea.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see at least two approaches to do this if you want to get rid of wrapper classes. The first is to use the Jackson Tree Model (`JsonNode`) and the second is to use a deserialization feature called `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`.

---

**Alternative 1: Use `JsonNode`**

When deserializing JSON using Jackson there are multiple ways to control what type of objects that are to be created. The `ObjectMapper` can deserialize the JSON to e.g. a `Map`, `JsonNode` (via the `readTree`-method) or a POJO.

If you combine the `readTree`-method with the `POJO` conversion the wrappers can be completely removed. Example:

```
// The author class (a bit cleaned up)
public class Author {
    private final String givenName;
    private final String surname;

    @JsonCreator
    public Author(
            @JsonProperty("given-name") final String givenName,
            @JsonProperty("surname") final String surname) {

        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
}
```

The deserialization can then look something like this:

```
// The JSON
final String json = "{\"authors\":{\"author\":[{\"given-name\":\"AdrienneH.\",\"surname\":\"Kovacs\"},{\"given-name\":\"Philip\",\"surname\":\"Moons\"}]}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Read the response as a tree model
final JsonNode response = mapper.readTree(json).path("authors").path("author");

// Create the collection type (since it is a collection of Authors)
final CollectionType collectionType =
        TypeFactory
                .defaultInstance()
                .constructCollectionType(List.class, Author.class);

// Convert the tree model to the collection (of Author-objects)
List<Author> authors = mapper.reader(collectionType).readValue(response);

// Now the authors-list is ready to use...
```

If you use this Tree Model-approach the wrapper classes can be completely removed.

---

**Alternative 2: remove one of the wrappers and unwrap the root value**
The second approach is to remove only one of the wrappers. Assume that you remove the `Authors` class but keep the `Response`-wrapper. If you add the a `@JsonRootName`-annotation you can later unwrap the top-level name.

```
@JsonRootName("authors") // This is new compared to your example
public class Response {
    private final List<Author> authors;

    @JsonCreator
    public Response(@JsonProperty("author") final List<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }

    @JsonProperty("author")
    public List<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
}
```

Then, for your mapper simply use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Unwrap the root value i.e. the "authors"
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
final Response responsePojo = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
```

The second approach only removes one of the wrapper classes but instead the parsing function is quite pretty.

Comment: I used Alternative 2 worked like a charm